# Erlang Universal Binary Format? Anyone using it?

Tags: interop, erlang, thrift, thrift-protocol

I recently stumbled upon this 2002 conference [paper](http://www.erlang.se/workshop/2002/Armstrong.pdf) (*Getting Erlang to talk to the outside world* by Joe Armstrong) and I was wondering whether this is a standard that was ignored or if there was any adoption?

Should I focus on Apache Thrift for inter-platform communication? *(whatever solution I choose will involve at least Erlang)*

Comment: FWIW apart from Thrift there's also at least [BERT-RPC](http://bert-rpc.org).

Comment: Thanks, Yasir. Am reading the spec.

Answer (score 8):

You might find the following information helpful about UBF (i.e. UBF User's Guide).

http://ubf.github.com/ubf/ubf-user-guide.en.html

This might help answer some of your questions about UBF.  There is also an Erlang server and client implementation of Thrift using the UBF framework (https://github.com/ubf/ubf-thrift).

Joe N.

p.s. We have been using UBF, EBF, and JSF in a production environment for approximately ~5 years.  The UBF contract checker is very helpful for developing, debugging, and deploying a system.

Answer (score 5):

UBF never really caught on. [Here's](http://armstrongonsoftware.blogspot.com/2008/07/ubf-and-vm-opcocde-design.html) what Armstrong had to say in 2008. As you look into Thrift you might also look into [Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/). You can find an Erlang implementation [here](https://github.com/basho/erlang_protobuffs).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if anyone's using Erlang's binary serialization format per se, outside of Erlang programs; but [BERT](http://bert-rpc.org/) (Binary ERlang Term) is an Erlang-compatible binary data interchange format and RPC protocol specified and open-sourced by the [GitHub](https://github.com/) guys. It's based on and fully binary-compatible with the Erlang external term format.

As you can see on the BERT website, there are implementations in a number of programming languages, including C++, JavaScript, Ruby, Python, Scala, Haskell, Go, Factor, Scheme, Clojure, and Common Lisp. The [mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/bert-rpc) currently has 85+ members subscribed to it, so quite a few people are indeed using BERT, and hence indirectly the Erlang binary format.

In [my own use](http://rdf.rubyforge.org/bert/), mostly in Ruby and Common Lisp applications, BERT has proved useful as essentially a binary form of S-expressions.

Answer (score 4):

I think the Hibari guys are using it.

https://github.com/ubf/ubf/